# Dice can never be balanced, I wants to prove this

Tags: probability-theory

1. When we roll a dice, due to gravitational force, fall towards earth.
2. Dice starts rolling, in this rolling, there is speed and direction so velocity is there.
3. Speed change gradually so acceleration is there.
4. According to the 2nd law of motion F=ma from here we can find that  a=F/m mean there is an inverse relationship between acceleration and mass, Greater mass lesser acceleration and vice versa.
5. And rolling speed of dice is reduced gradually. So there is also moment of inertia (resistance) and inertia is directly proportionate with mass. The more the greater mass the more the greater inertia.
6. I have a dice having the specification of Diameter=15mm.
7. Dice have 6 sides one side has one spot which has 6mm diameter with depth less than 2mm and all other spots have diameter 3.5mm and have depth More than 1 mm
8. From the above calculation I can decide easily that lesser material has been extracted from the side have one spot  than side that of the dice which has two spots because sum of both spots length is 7mm which is more than 6mm diameter of spot one.
9. On the basis of point 8 I can say side which has one spot is heavier than side the which has two spots and so on.
10. A side that hase greater mass will produce lesser acceleration according to point 4 and will has greater inertia according to point 5.
11. As compare to other sides, side the which has one spot has greater mass greater inertia and lesser acceleration so when dice is rolling this side will be with the ground and opposite side to this side have greater probability that is 6 as compare to other.
12. Mass of 1>2>3>4>5>6 due to difference in mass inertia and acceleration of each side will be different then how can occurrence every one will be same? The side that is opposite to the land side has more probability than any sides of the dice like this p(6)>p(5) >p(4) >p(3) >p(2) >p(1) hence a dice can never be balance.

is this enough or i need more?

Comment: Possibly more of a physics question than a probability theory question?

Answer (score 0):

Remains the question: *How* does the asymmetrical structure influence the probabilities (and does it at all)?

According to classical mechanics, the final outcome is *determined* by the initial spacial and angular positions and velocities at the moment you let go of the die. So where does probabilities enter in the first place? At most from the initial conditions, and then we need a distribution over these in order to begin the argument...

There are a couple of other problems with your list: Speaking of different inertia for the various faces is problematic as after all we are dealing with the die as a single rigid body. Maybe one should rather talk about the inertia tensor and the moments of inertia - it may happen even with the differently placed dots that there is no distinguished main axis and so symmetry is restored!

Nevertheless, we are still lacking a good model about how the kinetic energy gets "lost": This happens partly from air resistance (awfully complicated) and mainly from inelasticity of the bouncing events against the table.

A model that is likely (also) far from perfect, but I won't know anything better, is this from thermodynamics: Each of the final landing positions corresponds to a certain solid angle (i.e., proportion of a spherical surface) of orientations in some way closest to or attracted to the landing position. Also, each of the landing positions may correspond to a different potential energy (because the asymmetric mass distribution may lead to different heights of the centre of gravity). Then the probabilities of the final positions should follow Boltzmann's distribution - where the temperature depends on the (translational and angular) momentum the die starts with. If the die is asymmetric, the "temperature" will influence the probabilities. Hence a perfect die would have equal heights of the cog for all faces and also equal spatial angles associated with them.